# how to change a dashboard in virtual machine for another data using programming(python)

Tags: python, tableau-api

I have data source and using that data source i created a dashboard. now i inserted that dash board into my virtual machine.
now my question is how to update the dashboard  in virtual machine with new data using python or any method with out disturbing design

Comment: Tableau has an SDK you can explore. https://github.com/tableau

Comment: Dear Bernadro, 
 can you please explain how to do it. i am fresher to tableau and i have knowledge in python

Comment: Sorry, that is beyond my expertise. I was just pointing out the SDK exists.

Comment: thank you Bernardo